# Arcmap 10 Visual Basic

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcobjects, vba

im wondering if there is a way to build something like this in Arcmap 10 since VBA isnt supported anymore.

[image]

I need a tool to handle Polygons and their Information like in the picture with a simple window. I thought of a connection with a access Database.

Comment: What do you mean by handle? do you mean view and edit attributes?

Comment: Like a mask where you can type in an ID to search for specific polygons and to show their attributes (Like in the picture). Further more to edit the information and maybe a zoom to layer function.

Comment: the picutre is in German or other language, some people here can't read it - so a description of the functionality your are looking for is welcome.

Comment: I need something like Virtual Basic where i can create a window which is somehow connected to a database to show information for every polygon. So in this window i need some fields where text comes out of a linked database. Sorry its a bit hard to explain cause english is not my main language.

Comment: Shortly, you have an already made feature in arcmap to do edits to the [atrribute table from a window](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m90000000m000000). The other part is a select by attribute API which I'm not aware of one; the aim of this is not expliciltly written, and I think why create a code, where there is a tool with this functionality. Don't know about VBA in arcgis, but try looking into developing APIs in arcgis.

Comment: The idea behind is that someone who doesnt know gis can handle their agricultural areas by using that simple window. Maybe do some queries based on the database behind. Or to search areas with an ID and zoom to that area by clicking a button.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely achieve this with arcobjects in any of the .net languages.  Your question at this point is very broad.  Most of the technical aspects you will find many examples of when performing a internet search such as; how to create ArcGIS add-in button, how to connect to database table, how to populate a data grid based on sql SELECT query, arcobjects how to add a layer to a map document, arcobjects how to set query filter on layer and select a feature(s) based on a certain field/attribute value.  I would recommend the following general workflow to create this:

1. Create an ArcGIS add-in button (using Visual Studio)
2. When button is clicked it opens a windows form with some various drop down controls for selecting per-defined layers  (obviously you will need a database connection logic and sql SELECT query to populate the data grid (from a form control value selection) written to a feature set and added to the data grid).
3. Next, you will need logic/control events for triggering changes in the data grid and committing those back to the database (UPDATE queries)
4. In addition, you may include logic for the grid/record to open a context menu that would relate to a GIS feature add it to the map and perform a selection of the related feature for zooming, or panning to it.